# Checking for a multi-line regex match with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am having an issue matching a block, with header details, which later are going to be processed (the files). This is for all .java files.

**The problem, I assume so far, is that for some reason it doesn't seem to go to the next line, to match the next line (I might be wrong of course). It does match the block on regex101.com but when I run the script it doesn't seem to go to the next line.**

*I'm using Cygwin under Win7.*

Only the enabled pattern seems to match so far, but this matches *Example3* which I do NOT want; I only want to match *Example1* and *Example2*.

This is my script so far:

```
# !/bin/bash
# Script START - Info
printf "Search for header with X details - START\n"

# Get the total files
FILES_TOTAL=$(ls -l | find . | grep "\.java$" | wc -l)
printf "Files to process: $FILES_TOTAL\n"

# Total nr. of various files
COUNTER_N=0
COUNTER_Y=0

# Set the files to be manipulated (all .java files)
SEARCH=$(find . | grep "\/uk\/" | grep "\.java$")

# Set the pattern for the header to search for
PATTERN='(.*DIGITAL.*)'
# PATTERN="(.*DIGITAL.*)"

############ THE PATTERN IS INCOMPLETE, FOR SOME REASON THE OTHER PATTERNS DO NOT WORK,
############ IT DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK THE NEW LINE/FEED
# PATTERN='(\/\*\*\r\n)(.*DIGITAL)'
# PATTERN="(\/\*\*\r\n)(.*DIGITAL)"
# PATTERN='(.*DIGITAL.*\n)(.*MILAN.*\n)(.*STOCK.*\n)(.*TEL.*\n)'
# PATTERN="(.*DIGITAL.*\n)(.*MILAN.*\n)(.*STOCK.*\n)(.*TEL.*\n)"
# PATTERN='(\/\*\*\n)(.*DIGITAL.*\n)(.*MILAN.*\n)(.*STOCK.*\n)(.*TEL.*\n)((.*\*\n?(\/?)){0,})'
# PATTERN="(\/\*\*\n)(.*DIGITAL.*\n)(.*MILAN.*\n)(.*STOCK.*\n)(.*TEL.*\n)((.*\*\n?(\/?)){0,})"
# PATTERN='(\/\*\*\n)(.*DIGITAL.*\n)(.*MILAN.*\n)(.*STOCK.*\n)(.*TEL.*\n)((.*\*\n?(\/?)){0,})/g'
# PATTERN="(\/\*\*\n)(.*DIGITAL.*\n)(.*MILAN.*\n)(.*STOCK.*\n)(.*TEL.*\n)((.*\*\n?(\/?)){0,})/g"

# For each .java file found
for file in "$SEARCH"; do       
    # Process files
    if egrep -q "$PATTERN" "$file"; then
        printf "Has the header: $file \n"
        let COUNTER_Y=COUNTER_Y+1
    else
        # printf "Does NOT have the header: $file "\n"
        let COUNTER_N=COUNTER_N+1
    fi

    # Update nr. of files
    let FILES_PROCESSED=COUNTER_Y+COUNTER_N
done

# Script END - Info/Report
printf "Search for header with X details - END\n"
printf "Files - NO header: $COUNTER_N"
printf "Files - YES header: $COUNTER_Y"
printf "Total files processed: $FILES_PROCESSED"
```

It matches perfectly for what I want (*Example1* & *Example2*) on the web, but it does not work in the script!
There is a sample file and the regex matching the block here:
https://regex101.com/r/kG5iK7/2

What's going on here?! Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you need to specify global search perhaps?

Comment: It is specified at the end? for PATERN 9 and 10 (commented out in my script). It didn' work though

Comment: BTW, the native bash regex mechanism is `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`; it's worth being explicit that your question and answer are around grep, so folks don't wander in looking for info about the other mechanism.

Comment: (there are other best-practice issues in the code in the question -- I focused below only on those shown in the answer, but consider running through http://shellcheck.net/ and reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind -- a list of arbitrary filenames can only be safely stored in an *array*, not a single string variable).

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was matching the multi line pattern.
Therefore this did the trick:

```
if grep -Pz "$PATTERN" "$file"; then
```

`-P` activate perl-regexp for grep

`-z` suppress newline at the end of line

Thanks to @Charles Duffy for reminding the good practice code.

Comment: Needs more quotes (unless the shell at hand is zsh); see http://shellcheck.net/ for backup there. And the parenthesis just make your code less efficient; take them out. And `-z` doesn't just suppress a newline, it **adds a NUL**; is that really what's desired here?

Comment: `if grep -Pz "$PATTERN" "$file"; then` would be the formulation with the parens (and thus the unnecessary subshell) removed and the quotes added.

Comment: What I needed in this part of the script is to match precisely the files which I will process later on. I have tried way before posting, all the quotes and other formats. The issue was making the regex go to the next line, this was possible using -P and -z

Comment: As stated I am using Cygwin (latest version to current date 08/2016) under Win7

Comment: Agreed with you @Charles, I am inclined to use good practice code. I will make an edit. Thanks for your help.